# Simon says analyser / Beat Simon says

Tags: java, image, screenshot, mouse, awtrobot

I want to code a program in java, which can "beat" Simon says(which runs in my browser(!) on some website).

So my java application has to:

1. work in the background
2. screenshot my screen every few seconds and recognize the color
   which lighted up, save that information (e.g. in an ArrayList)
3. press the fields in the right order
4. do that "infinite" times

I have no idea how to run my application in the background(1.), I can do something simple like counting. But I want it to actually do something like use my mouse to move to the right position and then click it(while running in the background).

I would realize the 2nd task by using the Robot java class [createScreenCapture() to get the BufferedImage and then analyze that]
If you have a better idea, please let me know.

The 3rd task can as well be realized though the Robot class by using mouseMove(int x, int y) and mousePress(int buttons).

So I hope you can help me with that background thing, and excuse my bad English skills.

My code so far:

```js
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BeatSimon {

 private ArrayList<Integer> order;
 private Robot robot;
 private int round;

 public BeatSimon() throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
  order = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  robot = new Robot();
  round = 1;
  start();
 }

 public void start() throws InterruptedException {
  BufferedImage aktImage;
  order = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  aktImage = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080));
  // get the order
  for (int i = 0; i < this.round; i++) {
   if (aktImage.getRGB(0, 0) == 0) // I don't have the specific coordinates or color yet
    order.add(0);
   else if (aktImage.getRGB(1, 1) == 1)
    order.add(1);
   else if (aktImage.getRGB(2, 2) == 2)
    order.add(2);
   Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
  
  //press the fields in the right order
  for (int i = 0; i < this.round; i++) {
   if (order.get(i) == 0) {
    robot.mouseMove(0, 0);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
   } else if (order.get(i) == 1) {
    robot.mouseMove(1, 1);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
   } else if (order.get(i) == 2) {
    robot.mouseMove(2, 2);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
   }
   Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
  this.round += 1;
  start();
 }
}
```

Comment: You'd be much better off doing it in JavaScript and inputing the code directly in the console of your browser.

Comment: I've never worked with JavaScript to be honest.. Do you have any tips on how to approch it? Maybe even just learning the specific things I'd need to get this task done, without having to learn JavaScript entirely?

Comment: Have you done *any* coding for this yet?

Comment: @Dupstre Well there's quite a lot of things to know that are specific to JavaScript, if you have no other interest in the language it would probably be a waste of time then...

Comment: @ScottHunter added my code so far